# I am new to react Native can anyone suggest me a simple approach for react native Design

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-native

Currently i am working on a project it has react and react native technologies.we have used sass for designing the react app, now i want to do the same for the React native but it seems so many CSS properties are not supporting in 
react native like display, pseudo classes and border properties,positions...etc, so it is difficult for me to design 
a react native app so can any one suggest me a better approach/simple way to design a react native app.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack overflow isn't the website to ask these types of questions please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Respectfully, you should try the basics first:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html